# Hide parent div and show ui-view in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to hide the div "whole" when click on #clickit so that my setting page content won't show and .user page will show in ui-view

setting html page

```
 <!-- page content -->
       <div class="whole">
            <div class="page-title">
              <div class="title_left">
                <h3>Settings</h3>
              </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row" id="clickit"> // <-- Click to hide "whole" class
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <a ui-sref=".user">Users & practitioners</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

         <div  ui-view> // I HAVE TO SHOW THIS DIV AND HIDE SETTING DIV
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->
```

I don't want a jquery solution.. all i need a angular of pure javascript solution

Comment: how can you show the div in which ui-view is there when the entire thing is nested inside whole. If you hide whole it will hide everything as of now on your code! Be more clear on your question please..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="whole" ng-hide="hideWhole> // <-- assign a scope var dependency
    <div class="page-title">
        <div class="title_left">
            <h3>Settings</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row" id="clickit" ng-click="hideWhole=1"> // <-- update scope var
```

Ideally you'll use a controller variable (`ctrl.hideWhole` in controllerAs syntax) so you can update the display of the element from elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript solution to your problem, attaching a function to the onclick event of your element which sets the css display attribute to none.

```
<div class="row" id="clickit" onclick="hideWhole()">
function hideWhole() {
    var wholeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(".whole");
    wholeDiv.style.display = 'none'; 
}
```